# Printing out a number odd amount of times in an array

Tags: python, arrays

```
list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]

for int in list:
    e = list.count(int)
    if (e%2) == 1:
        print(int)
```

So in this code I am trying to get the number that is in the list odd amount of times and print it out. In this case the number 3 is the only one that appears an odd amount of times. But instead of just printing out `3` it prints out

```
3
3
3
```

How would i make it just to print out `3`?

Answer (score 2):

you could create a set of numbers that appear an odd number of times in the array, append to that set instead of printing immediately, and then after you first loop, print everything in that set. Also, don't use reserved keywords for variable names.

```
nums = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
odds = set()
for i in nums:
    e = nums.count(i)
    if (e%2) == 1:
        odds.add(i)

for i in list(odds):
    print(i)
```

Comment: I am trying to get the number that is odd amount of times not how many times it's in... Sorry if i wasn't clear enough

Comment: `odds.add(i)` instead then

Comment: Fixed now. was on my phone haha

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of instances, then print out which occur an odd number of times.

```py
from collections import Counter

l = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
for k, v in Counter(l).items():
    if v % 2 == 1:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You print it out three times, because you check the count for *each appearance* of the number in the list.  Since `3` appears 3 times, you count and print it 3 times.

You need to iterate over a list of *unique* values.  For this, we generally use a `set`.  In your program, the change is one simple expression:

```
# Do not use a built-in type name as a variable
population = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]

for i in set(population):
```

Continue with your regularly scheduled program.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of your list cast as a set cast as a list. A set is a type of itterable that cannot have duplicates.

```
st = list(set(list))
```

Instead of `for int in list:`, now use `for int in st:`. By doing this, you will be iterating through all *unique* values in the input list and counting how many times they show up.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out 'int' and it is printing out the integer that is odd.
So if you want the output to be the total number of odd integers in the array, you should add a variable, say counter, that would update/add 1 to itself every time the condition is true.

One implementation can be done like this:

```
list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
counter = 0

for int in list:
    e = list.count(int)
    if (e%2) == 1:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```